# Proving that in a complete metric space $(X,d)$ with $X=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, some $A_n$ are not nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a complete metric space $(X,d)$ with $\{A_n\}$ a sequence of subsets of $X$ and $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Show that  $A_n$ is not nowhere dense for some $n$.

Here is my attempted proof, but I'm not sure if it is correct or complete. Any comments and alternative proofs are highly welcome.

From the Baire's category theorem we have that $(X,d)$ is a Baire space, so that every nonempty open set in $X$ is not a meagre set. Now suppose that $A_n$ is nowhere dense for all $n$, then $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is by definition a meagre set. However, $X$ is an open set in the Baire space $(X,d)$, therefore it cannot be a meagre set, a contradiction.

Comment: This is quite correct, indeed.